# Maven javadoc plugin how to exclude generated source

Tags: maven, javadoc

Some maven plugin can generate additional source code e.g., jaxb2.

I want to skip generating javadocs from `target/generated-sources` directory.

How to configure `maven-javadoc-plugin` to achieve this?  Maybe there is some other way?

Answer (score 6):

There is:

```
<sourceFileExcludes>
        <sourceFileExclude>**/dir_name/*.java</sourceFileExclude>
</sourceFileExcludes>
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work for me - the aggregate-jar step still logs out warnings for generated sources, despite me using the patterns **/generated-sources/** or **/*_.java - on javadoc plugin version 3.2.0

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you can exclude based on directory, but you can use the `<excludePackageNames>` tag to exclude based on the package. (See [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/exclude-package-names.html).) Does you autogenerated code all have the same Java package?

Comment: Unfortunately, standard code and generated code has the same package.

Answer (score 2):

A simple and effective solution is to generate the code to a new package (for example: using ANTLR, move the grammars one layer deeper, from a `your.package.here` into a new `your.package.here.antlr` package).

Then, using Andrew Rueckert's suggestion, add `<excludePackageNames>*.antlr</excludePackageNames>` in the maven javadoc plugin configuration in your pom file.

Answer (score 1):

And another possible solution is to set `<sourceFileIncludes>`, e.g:

```
<sourceFileIncludes>**/com/pany/different/package/**/*.java</sourceFileIncludes>
```

Works only if your main source dirs ends differently from generated sources.